# MATLAB meshgrid error

Tags: matlab

I am using the meshgrid in one of my matlab functions which is called in a loop and the particular line of code is as follows (Sorry I cannot paste full code here)

```
rect
[m,n] = meshgrid(rect(1):rect(3),rect(2):rect(4));
size(m)
```

Now I am printing rect and size(m) displayed as ans in output alongwith the meshgrid code. I am posting below the last two iterations where

1) The first one which gives size(m) as 46x48 is the right dimension and does not throw up an error at the matrix addition I do at a later stage.

2) The second one which shows size(m) as 46x47 is the wrong dimension though the rect values suggest otherwise.

```
rect =

  119.9290   69.3807  166.9290  114.3807


ans =

    46    48


rect =

  120.0508   69.5380  167.0508  114.5380


ans =

    46    47

Error using  + 
Matrix dimensions must agree.
```

Now I take the same numbers and do a meshgrid in the command window and the results are right as follows

```
>> [lm,kl] = meshgrid(120.0508:167.0508,69.5380:114.5380);
>> size(lm)

ans =

    46    48
```

What maybe the reason for this anomaly?

Comment: Use `format long g;`, then display both rectangle arrays again.  You'll see that there is a small difference between them, and that's why you're getting different `meshgrid` results.  MATLAB by default displays up to 4 decimal points, so you typing in the numbers up to 4 decimal places manually doesn't fully capture the entire precision of the actual numbers captured in your rectangle.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably experiencing floating point precision errors. To have a solution robust against small precision errors, I recommend to switch to linspace.

```
[m,n] = meshgrid(linspace(rect(1),rect(3),round(rect(3)-rect(1)+1),linspace(rect(2),rect(4),round(rect(4)-rect(2)+1))
```

As an alternative, you could add some small number to the second value. This will make sure that the difference is always slightly larger than the integer distance, not slightly smaller.

```
[m,n] = meshgrid(rect(1):(rect(3)+0.1),rect(2):(rect(4)+0.1));
```

Comment: Thanks. But this small perturbation induces a noticeable error due to accumulation in the final output of my application(tracking an object in an image) when run over many iterations. Any other workarounds you know of?